# Como validar que al seleccionar el checkbox los input file sean obligatorios

Tags: html

Estoy en la creación  de un formulario en el cual debo cargar dos archivos, pero requiero que la carga de estos archivos sean obligatorios al momento de seleccionar el checkbox, el creado el siguiente código para construir parte de mi formulario en donde tengo el chekbox y los dos input file para carga de archivos:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Seleccione:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin: 0 14px 0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="cartaPrt" name="Checkbox" value="chkboxFile" class="checkfiles">
              </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="form-group row div_a_mostrar" id="ArchivoPDF1">
                        <label for="ToUpload2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo 1:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="ToUpload1" id="ToUpload1" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()">
              </div>
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group row div_a_mostrar" id="ArchivoPDF2">
                         <label for="ToUpload2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo 2:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="ToUpload2" id="ToUpload2" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()">
              </div>
                    </div> 

<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Archivos</button>
      </div>
```

Alguien puede darme una orientación en como realizar este tipo de validación ?

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo podemos realizar con JQuery, al momento de seleccionar el **Check** escuchamos el evento, si es **checked**, habilitamos la propiedad **required**, al desmarcar el check eliminamos dicha propiedad, quedaría algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#cartaPrt").on('click', function() {

    if ($('#cartaPrt').is(':checked')) {
      $('#ToUpload1').prop('required', true);
      $('#ToUpload2').prop('required', true);
      alert('Es obligatorio seleccionar los dos archivos');
    } else {
      $('#ToUpload1').removeAttr('required');
      $('#ToUpload2').removeAttr('required');
      alert('No es obligatorio seleccionar los dos archivos');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Seleccione:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin: 0 14px 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cartaPrt" name="Checkbox" value="chkboxFile" class="checkfiles">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row div_a_mostrar" id="ArchivoPDF1">
        <label for="ToUpload2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo 1:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="file" name="ToUpload1" id="ToUpload1" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row div_a_mostrar" id="ArchivoPDF2">
          <label for="ToUpload2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo 2:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="file" name="ToUpload2" id="ToUpload2" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()">

          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Archivos</button>
          </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Puedes inspeccionar el elemento y veras que se agrega o elimina la propiedad **required**. Me dices si te sirvió.